# Show datat-content when hover on glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign

Tags: jquery

I am showing some information when mouse hovering on glyphicon sign. The code is working now but only for `add content`. I want to uses the same JQuery code for edit, delete ..ect.  I do not want to repeat the Jquery code again and again.

How to do that?

HTML:

```
<input name="add" value="1" type="checkbox"  /> 
Add Contents  
<a href="#"  title="Add" data-content="1- Problem Report. 2- Maintenance Report. 3- Expeses Report. 4- Add Contract. 5-Items">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" id="add_inf"></span>
</a> 

<input name="edit" value="1" type="checkbox" /> 
Edit Contents 
<a href="#" title="Edit" data-content="1- Problem Report. 2- Maintenance Report. 3- Expeses Report. 4- Contract.">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" id="edit_inf"></span>
</a>

<input name="delete" value="1" type="checkbox" /> 
Delete Content
<a href="#" title="Delete" data-content="1- Problem Report. 2- Maintenance Report. 3- Expeses Report. 4- Contract. 5-Items">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" id="delete_inf"></span>
</a>
```

JQuery:

```
var $btn2 = $('#add_inf');
$btn2.data('state', 'hover');

var enterShow = function () {
    if ($btn2.data('state') === 'hover') {
        $btn2.popover('show');
    }
};

var exitHide = function () {
    if ($btn2.data('state') === 'hover') {
        $btn2.popover('hide');
    }
};

var clickToggle = function () {
    if ($btn2.data('state') === 'hover') {
        $btn2.data('state', 'pinned');
    } else {
        $btn2.data('state', 'hover')
        $btn.popover('hover');
    }
};

$btn2.popover({ trigger: 'manual' })
    .on('mouseenter', enterShow)
    .on('mouseleave', exitHide)
    .on('click', clickToggle);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only works for `Add content` because you have assigned these events only to it.

Here:

```
var $btn2 = $('#add_inf');
```

You need to assign it to all of your `glyphicon`s:

```
var $btn2 = $('#add_inf, #edit_inf, #delete_inf');
```

or even much better using classes:

```
var $btn2 = $('.glyphicon.glyphicon-info-sign'); // or another custom one
```

Note that in your events, in order to show popover not for all events, but only for the active one, you need to work with the triggered object using `this`:

```
function enterShow() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('state') === 'hover') {
        $this.popover('show');
    }
};
function exitHide() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('state') === 'hover') {
        $this.popover('hide');
    }
};

function clickToggle() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('state') === 'hover') {
        $this.data('state', 'pinned');
    } else {
        $this.data('state', 'hover')
        $this.popover('hover');
    }
};
```

Note how I have changed the declaration of a function. Use this one, when possible. [(Why?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)